# AscyncTask - Not on the main thread

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

First, sorry for my bad english, I'm portuguese speaker and surely I will make some english grammar mistake.

Well, I'm trying to do a AsyncTask Class to load a map from googleMap, but it's showing this error message:

```
06-25 18:47:03.062: E/AndroidRuntime(8021): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-25 18:47:03.062: E/AndroidRuntime(8021): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-25 18:47:03.062: E/AndroidRuntime(8021):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-25 18:47:03.062: E/AndroidRuntime(8021): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on the main thread
```

My main class what calls the AsyncTask class

```
public class ExemploGPSSimples extends FragmentActivity {

    protected GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        setContentView(R.layout.exmeplo_gps);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        configuraGPS();
    }

    private void configuraGPS() {
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_gps);
        map = mapFragment.getMap();
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);  
        //LatLng local=pegaPosicaoAtual();
        Localizador localizador = new Localizador(this);
        String endereco="Av. João Pessoa, 1091, Porto Alegre, RS";
        LatLng local = localizador.getEndereco(endereco);
        SincronizaMapa sincronizaMapa = new SincronizaMapa(this,local,map);
        sincronizaMapa.execute();
        adicionaMarcador(map,local);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);     
    }

    private void adicionaMarcador(GoogleMap map2, LatLng local) {
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(local).title("Luiz").snippet("Casa");
        Marker marker = map2.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }


}
```

and finally the AsyncTask class

```
public class SincronizaMapa extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private final Activity activity;
    private final LatLng local;
    private final GoogleMap map;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public SincronizaMapa(Activity activity, LatLng local,
            GoogleMap map) {
                this.activity = activity;
                this.local = local;
                this.map = map;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "Sincronizando mapa", "Aguarde...",true,true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        CameraPosition position = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(local)
        .bearing(0)
        .tilt(0)
        .zoom(17)
        .build();
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(position);
        map.animateCamera(update);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

Thank you all for helping.

Comment: Don't worry; your English is excellent. Better than many Americans, IMHO.

Answer (score 8):

map.animate modifies a UI component (the map), so that must be done on the UI thread.
You can move code that needs to be on the UI thread to onPostExecute

Comment: Besides I would say there is not need for an asynctask here, because there is no heavy processing in the doInBackground method!

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are trying to update the UI from a thread other than the UI thread. asyncTasks allow you to do background work (doInBackgroud) while keeping the UI thread free and then update the UI accodingly (onPostExecute).

You should put the body of doInBackground in the body of onPostExecute - the method that runs on the UI thread.